# Show articles of the Category in Subcategories

Tags: articles, category, subcategories

I am using Joomla 3 and I want to know how do to display the articles of the main category in the subcategories in a blog layout:

```
> Category Project
    * Article Global
    > City 1
        * Article Global
        * Article City 1
    > City 2
        * Article Global
        * Article City 2
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Menu Item:
   Menu item Type:: Articles >> List All Category >>
2. In Tab "Category" look for "Subcategories Levels"; Choos "ALL";

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is to display the articles of the subcategories in the category, on I need the site have a category called Project and it has subcategories with cities names to define the locations of the projects, but has some projects that has in all cities and need appear in all subcategories.

Comment: In joomla you cant select multi categories In same article. You can consider use a component like Zoo or K2. With this components you can do this.